# How to insert b-quote, del, ins, img, more, close tags buttons in tinymce`s "text" tab

Tags: tinymce

I have a tinymce editor in my wordpress admin page.
I tried to find in the tinymce documentation without finding the solution.
I would like insert b-quote, del, ins, img, more, close tags buttons in tinymce`s "text" tab like this :

[image]

How can I do this in a json array ?

Answer (score 0):

The text tab for WordPress is actually not using TinyMCE at all so you won't be able to address this via TinyMCE.  TinyMCE is the Visual Editor but it is not in use with the Text tab.